# Codeigniter: Weird behaviour of $this->db->like()

Tags: codeigniter

I've written a simple query for searching a keyword in the database.

```
$keyword = "keyword sample"; 
$keyword = str_replace(" ", "%", $keyword);   

$this->db->select('*')->from('table')
           ->like('column', "%".$keyword."%")->get();
```

Now the query generated by Codeigniter is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`table`) WHERE `column` LIKE '%keyword\%sample%'
```

Where is the trailing `\` coming from in the query? This is making an erroneous search and not returning the data that is actually in the db. I've checked everything and nothing seems to be wrong with the code I've written. Please help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you dig a bit into CodeIgniter's internals, you'll notice that the `$this->db->like()` function escapes special characters it contains - including, of course, `%`.

I don't think `like()` will help you much with your particular needs. Your best bet, I guess, would be to bypass the problem and use a `where` function containing your `LIKE` clause:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('table')->where("column LIKE '%$keyword%'")->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: ...("column LIKE %$keyword%")... , don't forget to insert single quotation, so it should be ...("column LIKE '%$keyword%'")...

Comment: You're absolutely right, I fixed the query. My bad.

Answer (score 23):

You just try it like this:

```
$this->db->select('*')
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->like('column', $keyword);
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

If you want to control where the wildcard (%) is placed, you can use an optional third argument. Your options are 'before', 'after' and 'both' (which is the default).

example:

```
$this->db->select('*')
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->like('column', $keyword, 'before');
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

If you do not want to use the wildcard (%) you can pass to the optional third argument the option 'none'.

example:

```
$this->db->select('*')
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->like('column', $keyword, 'none');
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

BUT, for your example you must need to search like `"%keyword sample%"`, or like `"%keyword%" OR "%simple%"`;

For example:

```
$this->db->like('column', 'keyword simple');
// Produces: WHERE column LIKE '%keyword simple%'
```

OR

```
$this->db->like('column', 'keyword');
$this->db->or_like('column', 'simple');
// Produces: WHERE column LIKE '%keyword%' OR column LIKE '%simple%'
```

More, you can read [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `escape_like_str()` method.

The `escape_like_str()` method should be used when strings are to be used in `LIKE` conditions so that `LIKE` wildcards `%`, `_` in the string are also properly escaped. It cannot automatically add the `ESCAPE` `!` condition for you, and so you’ll have to manually do that.

Hope it helps.

```
$keyword = "keyword sample"; 
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%" .
$this->db->escape_like_str($keyword)."%' ESCAPE '!'";
```

Source:- https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html