# how to fetch record in codeigniter where clause using json values

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

My question is in my table stored json encoded values like 
`field Name : offer_promotion`

```
 [{"name":"sample promotion","price":"1555","expdate":"2017-05-15","shortdesc":"test","longdesc":"test"}]
```

Now i want to write query for select records like, 
For eaxmple:

```
$this->db->where('offer_promotion', "name":"sample promotion");
```

How to write this query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544195/codeigniter-weird-behaviour-of-this-db-like check Erman Belegu answer.

Answer (score 3):

json in database works as a simple string.
So you have to apply logic similar as string.
You can use Like

```
$this->db->like('offer_promotion', '%"name":"sample promotion"%');
```

Comment: @KarthikSaravanan, Welcome in SO. This link may be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

1. `$some = json_decode($json);`
2. `$this->db->where('offer_promotion',$some['name']);`

Comment: How can we use php code ` json_decode($json)` in query?