# Comparing first 4 characters from table and fetching data from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two different `tables` as `testimonial` and `pagetitles`. While fetching the `Pagetitles` from `database`. I need to compare first 4 characters if both matches then I should get the data.

```
function getpagetitle($id)
{

    $this->db->select('P.*,T.testimonial_name');        
    $this->db->from('pagetitle AS P');      
    $this->db->join('testimonials AS T','SUBSTR(T.testimonial_name, 4) = SUBSTR(P.page_title, 4)','INNER');
    $this->db->where(array('P.page_title'=>$id));       
    $q=$this->db->get();        
    //var_dump($this->db->last_query());
    //print_r($q->num_rows());
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    $output = $q->result();

   return $output[0];
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Database tables

**testimonials:**

```
+----------------+-------------------+-------------+
| testimonial_id |  testimonial_name | client_name |
+----------------+-------------------+-------------+
| 1              |  testimonial      | abc         |
| 2              |  testimonial      | def         |
+----------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

**Pagetitle**

```
+--------------+-------------+
| pagetitle_id | pagetitle   |   
+--------------+-------------+
|  1           | testimonial |
|  2           | career      |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22544195/4229270

Comment: @Sinto here they are using like operator if the testimonial_name is testimonial and page_title is testimonials then it will not match then how can we get the data for this purpose i need to compare only first 4 characters

Comment: Try using ***SUBSTR(`T`.`testimonial_name`, 4) = SUBSTR(`P`.`page_title`, 4)*** in your join.

Comment: @Sinto can you edit in my code

Comment: Is it helpful.?

Comment: @Sinto getting database error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '4) = SUBSTR(P.page_title, 4) WHERE `P`.`page_title` = 'testimonial'' at line 3

SELECT `P`.*, `T`.`testimonial_name` FROM (`pagetitle` AS P) INNER JOIN `testimonials` AS T ON `SUBSTR`(`T`.`testimonial_name,` 4) = SUBSTR(P.page_title, 4) WHERE `P`.`page_title` = 'testimonial'

Comment: I will check that.

Comment: Any solution how to do that

Comment: Yes, but conveting to codeigniter some issues are coming up. An example query is this: SELECT * FROM (`contacts` c) JOIN `users` u ON ((SUBSTR(`u`.`first_name`, 1, 4)) = (SUBSTR(`c`.`first_name`, 1, 4))) WHERE `c`.`status` = 1 AND `c`.`first_name` != ''. I'm trying to convert as your required

Comment: Sorry, I'm also stuck in a issue. I have added a post, its answer will be your fix(http://stackoverflow.com/q/43995039/4229270)

Comment: Do you get any solution? I got one, but its not the correct answer for your issue but can be done. And will solve your problem. Do the same code using `query()`

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to use [if then statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) in mysql , 
so if we want to change your query , it must be something like this  :

```
select P.*,T.testimonial_name from pagetitle AS P , testimonials as T (
 select IF 'SUBSTR(T.testimonial_name, 4) = SUBSTR(P.page_title, 4)'  
 where P.page_title>5
)
```

i dont test it , but i think it must be true

Comment: Not understanding the query

Comment: @user8001297 this query tell to mysql that , until SUBSTR(T.testimonial_name, 4) = SUBSTR(P.page_title, 4) is false, dont select from where title >5  , so if the statement is true , your query will be lunch

Answer (score 1):

If you do not got any solutions yet try this below code,

```
$testimonials = $this->db->query("SELECT `P`.*, `T`.`testimonial_name` 
FROM (`pagetitle` P) INNER JOIN `testimonials` T ON 
((SUBSTR(`T`.`testimonial_name`, 1, 4)) = (SUBSTR(`P`.`page_title`, 1, 4))) 
WHERE `P`.`page_title` = SUBSTR('{$id}', 1, 4)")->result_array();
print_r($testimonials);
/* Output of $testimonials will be like below:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fieldname_1] => val
            [fieldname_2] => val
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fieldname_1] => val
            [fieldname_2] => val
        )
)
*/
if(count($testimonials) > 0) {
//$output = $testimonials->result();
return $testimonials[0];
} else {
return false;
}
```

Comment: Getting error as unkonwn column testimonial in where clause

Comment: Were we have "testimonial" in our query? Also there is no such column in your specified 'Database tables'

Comment: testimonial is my page title,there is no such column with testimonial

Comment: $testimonials = $this->db->query("SELECT `P`.*, `T`.`testimonial_name` 
FROM (`pagetitle` P) INNER JOIN `testimonials` T ON 
((SUBSTR(`T`.`testimonial_name`, 1, 4)) = (SUBSTR(`P`.`page_title`, 1, 4))) 
WHERE `P`.`page_title` = '{$id}'")->result_array();
//print_r($testimonials);
     
  if($testimonials->num_rows()>0)
       {
  $output = $testimonials->result();
  
       return $output[0];
   }
     else
  {
  return false;
  }

Comment: There you no need to check `num_rows` do `count($testimonials)` & `$output = $restimonials`

Comment: Not getting what you are saying

Comment: getting error as trying to get property of non-object in controllers file

Comment: Do you get a output like in my code section while printing $testimonials

Comment: So you donot have any testimonials similar to what you where searching. AND please remove `$output = $testimonials->result();` this line of code as I did

Comment: in testimonial table i have testimonial_name as testimonial and in page title i have testimonials so i need to compare only first 4 characters then this sould right

Comment: Please give a value in your DB in `page_title` field as `$id`, pls check my  code

Comment: Nothing it is getting

Comment: What is you giving in `$id`. Print you  executed query using `print_r($this->db->last_query());` and please check query. This is from my query http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b66b5kp58