# Unnecessary quotes adding on sql while executing - codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, substr

while trying to do a select query I came into a situation where unnecessary quotes are injecting to it on execution. I'm working in Codeigniter. Trying to selects record which having first 4 characters same.
Code is:

```
$calendar = $this->db->select("c.first_name as cfn, u.first_name as ufn", false)
        ->from("{$this->tables['contacts']} c")
        ->join("{$this->tables['users']} u", " SUBSTR( u.first_name , 1 , 4) = SUBSTR( c.first_name , 1 , 4) ", '')
        ->where(array('c.status' => 1, 'c.first_name !=' => ''))
        ->get()->result_array();
```

I'm getting an error as:

```
FUNCTION dbname.SUBSTR does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing 
and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

SELECT c.first_name as cfn, u.first_name as ufn FROM (`contacts` c) 
JOIN `users` u ON `SUBSTR`( `u`.`first_name` , 1 , 4) = SUBSTR( c.first_name , 1 , 4) 
 WHERE `c`.`status` = 1 AND `c`.`first_name` != ''
```

*`SUBSTR`* on query is unexciting(single quote for SUBSTR).

Comment: If you can replace the JOIN with this code 
        ->join('{$this->tables[users]} u', ' SUBSTR( u.first_name , 1 , 4) = SUBSTR( c.first_name , 1 , 4) ', '')  just give a try. May works for you

Comment: @vanurag. No, its an error. Table 'dbname.{$this->tables[users]}' doesn't exist

Comment: CI 3.0 onwards have 4th parameter in join if you want to [escape values and identifiers](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#CI_DB_query_builder::join)

Comment: @karanthakkar, thanks for that point. So by using a `FALSE` as 4th parameter, does my issue got fix in CI 3.0. Because I'm using a lower viersion, I cant check that. Or what is the change you suggesting to avoid my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I has to fix this issue by doing:

```
$calendar = $this->db->query("SELECT c.first_name as cfn, u.first_name as ufn 
FROM (`contacts` c) JOIN `users` u ON 
((SUBSTR(`u`.`first_name`, 1, 4)) = (SUBSTR(`c`.`first_name`, 1, 4))) 
WHERE `c`.`status` = 1 AND `c`.`first_name` != ''")->result_array();
print_r($calendar);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once and I solved it by using

```
str_replace('"','',$string);
```

Comment: What is string here? And please note that for me issue is on execution time, does str_replace() fix that?