# Codeigniter SQL query not working with SPECIAL CHARACTERS in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, special-characters

I have a query being generated in codeigniter which is searching for a like with an ampersand (&). The query its generating works perfectly when querying the database directly, but codeigniter is not returning any results.

I have the following sql query in codeigniter:

```
$where = array('name' => '&');
$this->db->select('*, organisations.postcode, organisations.id ');
$this->db->limit(20, 0);
$this->db->from('organisations');
$this->db->join('contacts','contacts.id = organisations.main_contact_id','left');
$this->db->like($where);
$query=$this->db->get();
```

This is creating the query:

```
SELECT *, `organisations`.`postcode`, `organisations`.`id` FROM `organisations` LEFT JOIN `contacts` ON `contacts`.`id` = `organisations`.`main_contact_id` WHERE name LIKE '%&%' ESCAPE '!' LIMIT 20
```

The query works, codeigniter does not.

Comment: You can find your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22544695/6503363
<br>Hope it helps.

Comment: You can find your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22544695/6503363
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `ESCAPE` as :

```
WHERE name LIKE '%\!&%' ESCAPE '\!'
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/NHWMI4366)